# What is the maximum length of an Azure Active Directory (AAD) Joined VM?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, virtual-machine

I have an extremely controlling asset management team that has stipulated prefixes to my current naming convention for VMs in host pools for AVD.

The problem I face is if I implement the changes I surpass the 15-character limit.

If these devices are ONLY AAD joined is there an actual limit of characters that can be used to formulate a useful name? if so, what is the limit?

Answer (score 0):

The following official link gives details on the naming restrictions for Azure resources.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-name-rules

Here is the restriction for naming a VM. For a Windows machine, you can name a VM for up to 64 characters. Although the hostname can only be up to 15 characters, the actual resource name could be up to 64 characters.

[image]

While creating a new VM you can see that it allows up to 64 character names. However, the hostname is automatically trimmed to 15 characters when the name is more than 15 characters.

[image]